# Why can't I use my 64 GB SD card in my Nikon D60?

Tags: nikon, digital

I formatted a brand new 64GB SD card, but when I try to take a picture my Nikon D60 shows "Card is Full" and won't take a picture - see the upper left message in the attached pic.

I formatted first with Windows, and then within the Nikon, it formatted it, but then I get the message "Card is Full" even though the card is brand new

Does anyone know why this is happening?

[image: Nikon SD card is full!]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noted in [Nikon's knowledgebase](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14524/~/approved-memory-cards---d60), the D60 supports [SDHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDHC) cards, but implicitly not [SDXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC) (as SDXC is never mentioned in the page). This isn't surprising as the D60 was released in January 2008 and the SDXC standard was announced in January 2009. The SDHC standard has a largest possible size of 32 GB, hence your 64 GB card *must* be an SDXC card and is not compatible with your camera.

You'll need to get a 32 GB (or smaller) card for your camera, and check that it is SDHC, rather than SDXC.

Answer (score 4):

I found this post after making the same purchasing mistake. I looked up the difference between SDHC and SDXC standards, and realized that the primary difference is in the filesystem (FAT32 and exFAT, respectively).

On a mac, you can reformat that 64/128GB card and it will work perfectly well in your D40X. If you're on a mac, open up the Terminal.

---

Insert the card and run the command:

```
diskutil list
```

This will print out a list of all connected disks. Note the path to the card, which is `/dev/disk2` in our case. **Reformatting erases everything, so make sure you select the correct disk!**
[image: result of command <code>diskutil list</code>]

---

Replacing `/dev/disk_to_format` with your path, run:

```
diskutil unmount /dev/disk_to_format
```

This will free up the device for formatting.
[image: result of command <code>diskutil unmount /dev/disk2</code>]

---

Replacing `/dev/disk_to_format` with your path, run:

```
sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -c 64 -s 67108864 -v "D40X" /dev/disk_to_format
```

This will format the card as FAT32, with a cluster size of 64 sectors and a total size of 67108864 sectors (32GB) named "D40X". You may be required to enter your password.
[image: result of command <code>sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -c 64 -s 67108864 -v "D40X" /dev/disk2</code>]

---

You now have a 32GB SDHC card that will work with your D40X. Restoring the full capacity SDXC simply requires you to format it back to exFAT.